# How do I make graphics of this button better in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, game-development

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import*
###################################

screen = "START"

pygame.init()
window_width = 1000
window_height = 650
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("LOGO QUIZ")
#############################################
def button(normal, activated, x_pos, y_pos, length, height, func=None):
    button = pygame.image.load(normal)
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if (mousex>x_pos)and(mousex<(length+x_pos))and(mousey>y_pos)and(mousey<(y_pos+height)):
        button = pygame.image.load(activated)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN )and (event.button == 1):
            if (mousex>x_pos)and(mousex<(mousex+x_pos))and(mousey>y_pos)and(mousey<(y_pos+height)):
                func()
    window.blit(button,(x_pos, y_pos))



##        button = pygame.image.load(activated)
    window.blit(button,(x_pos, y_pos))
def START():
    global screen
    while screen != "QUIT":
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                screen = "QUIT"

        bg = pygame.image.load("START.png")
        window.blit(bg,(0,0))
        button("play_u.png", "play_a.png", 350, 200, 325, 75, game)
        pygame.display.update()

def game():
    global screen
    while screen != "QUIT":
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                screen = "QUIT"
        window.fill((20, 20, 20))
        pygame.display.update()



    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
START()


pygame.display.update()
```

The above code is for the start menu of my game, I made a START function to show the start screen and then the game function to run the main game later, in the button function I want to make it as when the mouse is hovered over the picture, it should change the picture(activated pic) but when I do this it takes lots of time it change , how do i shorten the time?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you call `pygame.event.get()` multiple times per frame; once in `START`, and once in `button`.

Think about what happends when there's a `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event in the queue, then `pygame.event.get()` is called in `START`: The event gets removed from the queue, and when `pygame.event.get()` is called in `button`, the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event is already gone and `if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN )` will never be `True`.

So instead of calling `for event in pygame.event.get():` in `START`, you could store the result of `pygame.event.get()` in a variable and iterate over that in `START` and `button`. This way, you won't lose events.

Here's an example:

```
...

def button(events, normal, activated, x_pos, y_pos, length, height, func=None):
    button = pygame.image.load(normal)
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if (mousex>x_pos)and(mousex<(length+x_pos))and(mousey>y_pos)and(mousey<(y_pos+height)):
        button = pygame.image.load(activated)

    # iterate over the list if events instead of calling pygame.event.get
    for event in events:
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN )and (event.button == 1):
            if (mousex>x_pos)and(mousex<(mousex+x_pos))and(mousey>y_pos)and(mousey<(y_pos+height)):
                func()
    window.blit(button,(x_pos, y_pos))

...

def START():
    global screen
    while screen != "QUIT":
        # store the list of events in a variable
        events = pygame.event.get()

        # iterate over the new list
        for event in events:
            if event.type == QUIT:
                screen = "QUIT"

        bg = pygame.image.load("START.png")
        window.blit(bg,(0,0))

        # pass the list of events to the button function
        button(events, "play_u.png", "play_a.png", 350, 200, 325, 75, game)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am a beginner so can u edit the code and post it

Comment: I did exactly what u said, but I am getting this error:                                                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\python project\Logo_Quiz\Game.py", line 55, in <module>
    START()
  File "C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\python project\Logo_Quiz\Game.py", line 38, in START
    button("play_u.png", "play_a.png", 350, 200, 340, 90, game)
  File "C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\python project\Logo_Quiz\Game.py", line 18, in button
    for event in events:
NameError: name 'events' is not defined

Comment: @AnshumanBharadwaj It looks like you forgot to add the `events` parameter to the `button` function

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, the code is working but is still slow, shall I do any more changes?